# Which column is being truncated?

Tags: sql-server

When SQL Server says this, how do you tell which column has the problem?

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 11
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Comment: I've never found a way.  I jsut have to look at the data going in and the size of the receiving fields.

Comment: This is one of the most irritating messages in sql server period. Obviously the engine knows which column, why can't it be included in the error message? This has been an open connect issue for years.